# How can I use vbscript to add or change permissions on a registry key?

Tags: windows-7, scripting, registry

I want to use vbscript (or some scripting language I can run locally on a windows 7 machine) and change a registry key's *permissions*.

I saw regini, but it's old, and I didn't see how to use it for my needs.  Specifically, as an example, I need to add:

`nt service\BFE` to the `HKLM\currentcontrolset\services\bfe\parameters\policy`.  Then I have to use advanced, add bfe, then use specific permissions such as set, read, query value, delete, but not full control.

How can I do this programmatically with a scripting language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [**regini.exe**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875566%28v=ws.11%29.aspx).

So I won't be able to set Users Full Control, but Everyone Full Control.

See the following articles for details on the values used in the regini script:

- [How to Use Regini.exe to Set Permissions on Registry Keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237607)
- [How to: Use a Script to Change Registry Permissions from the Command Line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245031/EN-US)

And here you have the VBScript that will use regini.exe and its script:

```
' Create a temp file with the script that regini.exe will use
'
set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFileName = oFSO.GetTempName
set oFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileName)
oFile.WriteLine "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\AlejaCMaTypelib [1 5 7 11 17]"
oFile.WriteLine "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\AlejaCMaCo\AlejaCMaApp [1 5 7 11 17]"
oFile.Close

' Change registry permissions with regini.exe
'
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "regini " & strFileName, 8, true

' Delete temp file
'
oFSO.DeleteFile strFileName

WScript.Echo "Done!"
```